# Where is G-d's name in Megillat Esther?

Tags: sources-mekorot, purim, megillat-esther, shemos-sacred-names, arizal

In Megillat Esther, [G-d’s Name is never explicitly mentioned](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26581/why-doesnt-g-ds-name-appear-in-megillath-esther/26583#26583), but what about implicitly? I was told that the Arizal (and perhaps the Vilna Gaon?) found many pesukim in which G-d’s Name is concealed. Where are those places?

Comment: https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/98357

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Pri Etz Chaim](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%A2%D7%A5_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8_%D7%A8%22%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%94_%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%95) of [Rav Chaim Vital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayyim_ben_Joseph_Vital), the instances of G-d's name encoded in Megillat Esther are:

> "היא "וכל" הנשים "יתנו, ר"ת הוה"י. לבדו עותה המלכה ושתי, ס"ת והה"י. ושתי המלכה לפניו ולא באה, ס"ת יהו"ה. "ומלכותה "יתן "המלך לרעותה "הטובה, ר"ת ויה"ה. "יום "ובמלאות "הימים "האלה, ר"ת יוה"ה. יהודי היה בשושן הבירה ושמו, ס"ת יהה"ו. כי כלתה אליו הרעה, ס"ת יהו"ה. ראה כי כלתה אליו, ס"ת היה"ו. "יבוא "המלך "והמן "היום, ר"ת יהו"ה. זה איננו שוה לי, ס"ת הוה"י. וגדולה למרדכי על זה ויאמרו, ס"ת היה"ו. יצא מלפני המלך ופני המן, ר"ת יהו"ה. עד כאן י"ב הויות. (ג' שמות של אהוה) 'אחשדרפני "המלך "ואל "הפחות, ר"ת אהו"ה. (ס"א "המלך "והמן "אל "המשתה ר"ת אהו"ה). "את "הלבוש "ואת "הסוס, ר"ת אהו"ה "אל "היהודים "ואל "האחשדרפנים, ר"ת אהו"ה. ד' שמות אהי"ה - הבירה אל יד הגי, ר"ת אהי"ה, הנשים אל יד הגי, ר"ת אהי"ה. אשר ישלטו היהודים המה, ר"ת אהיה. את ימי הפורים האלה, ר"ת אהי"ה:
>
> המלך ודתו ובהקבץ, ר"ת וה"ו. המלך וישניה ואת, ר"ת וה"ו וס"ת כה"ת. ויבא
>   התך ויגד, ר"ת וה"ו. (ס"א ותמאן המלכה ושתי, ר"ה וה"ו). (ס"א והשרים ויעש
>   המלך, ר"ת וו"ה). ויבוקש הדבר וימצא, ר"ת וה"ו. ויבא המלך והמן ר"ת וה"ו.
>   (ס"ת ה' שמות של הה"ה) מדינה ומדינה ככתבה, ס"ת הה"ה. ובזה הנערה באה,
>   ס"ת הה"ה. אביה ואמה לקחה, ס"ת הה"ה. ומה יעשה בה, ס"ת הה"ה. הפורים הזאת
>   השנית, ר"ת הה"ה. יעשה בכל מלכותו, ר"ת יב"מ, שם דע"ב, וגי' ב"ן. כי גדול
>   מרדכי, ס"ת יל"י. יתנו יקר לבעליהן, ר"ת יל"י. יד איש משרי, ס"ת שד"י.
>   לפני המלך אחשורוש, ס"ת יכ"ש. מרדכי להסיר שקו, ס"ת יר"ו. נופל על המטה,
>   ס"ת לל"ה. טעם הסכמת המן, לגזור הגזרה על ישראל באדר, יותר מבשאר חדשים,
>   מפני כי י"ב חדשים הם נגד י"ב צרופי הויה, והוא החודש הזה אשר צרופו
>   הוה"י בהיפך, אשר הוא סוד הדין. לכן הזכיר המן השם בהיפך, ז"ה איננ"ו
>   שו"ה ל"י, ס"ת הוה"י. ואסתר רצתה להמשיך את הרחמים, והזכירה הויה ביושר,
>   "יבא "המלך "והמן "היום, ר"ת יהו"ה.

Answer (score 6):

Let's do one better: where is G-d's name concealed in *all of Tanach*?  I'm looking for שם הוי"ה backwards and forwards, equally spaced from the beginning and end of four consecutive words (first letter, second letter, last letter, second to last letter, etc.), similar to most of the answers and comments posted so far.  I'm not going to pretend to understand the answer from R' Chaim Vital, so I'm not looking for anything similar to that.

For statistical validity: I didn't do any other experiments besides for debugging.  I didn't tune my search space to produce any result in particular, and I was planning to post this answer whatever the result turned out to be.

```
import collections, dataclasses, itertools, json, re, requests
books = ['Genesis', 'Exodus', 'Leviticus', 'Numbers', 'Deuteronomy', 'Joshua', 'Judges', 'I Samuel', 'II Samuel', 'I Kings', 'II Kings', 'Isaiah', 'Jeremiah', 'Ezekiel', 'Hosea', 'Joel', 'Amos', 'Obadiah', 'Jonah', 'Micah', 'Nahum', 'Habakkuk', 'Zephaniah', 'Haggai', 'Zechariah', 'Malachi', 'Psalms', 'Proverbs', 'Job', 'Song of Songs', 'Ruth', 'Lamentations', 'Ecclesiastes', 'Esther', 'Daniel', 'Ezra', 'Nehemiah', 'I Chronicles', 'II Chronicles']

def lettersonly(pasuk):
    #remove parsha markings
    pasuk = re.sub(r"[(][^)]*[)]", "", pasuk)
    #remove everything but letters and spaces
    pasuk = pasuk.replace("־", " ")
    pasuk = re.sub(r"[^\s\w]", "", pasuk)
    return pasuk

def fourwise(iterable): #from pairwise from the itertools docs
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b, c, d = itertools.tee(iterable, 4)
    next(b, None)
    next(c, None); next(c, None)
    next(d, None); next(d, None); next(d, None)
    return zip(a, b, c, d)

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Result:
    forwards: list = dataclasses.field(default_factory=list)
    backwards: list = dataclasses.field(default_factory=list)
    npesukim: int = 0
    nwords: int = 0
    nletters: int = 0
    npermutations: int = 0
    def __add__(self, other):
        if not other: other = Result()
        return Result(self.forwards+other.forwards, self.backwards+other.backwards, self.npesukim+other.npesukim, self.nwords+other.nwords, self.nletters+other.nletters, self.npermutations+other.npermutations)
    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self+other
    @property
    def density(self): return len(self.forwards+self.backwards) / (2*self.npermutations)

def gatherresults(book):
    perek = book+" 1"
    forwards = []
    backwards = []
    npesukim = nwords = nletters = npermutations = 0
    while perek is not None:
        print(perek)
        j = json.loads(b"".join((requests.get("http://www.sefaria.org/api/texts/"+perek))))
        for i, pasuk in enumerate(j["he"], start=1):
            npesukim += 1
            pasuk = lettersonly(pasuk)
            allwords = pasuk.split()
            nwords += len(allwords)
            nletters += sum(len(word) for word in allwords)
            for words in fourwise(allwords):
                minlen = min(len(word) for word in words)
                for k in range(-minlen, minlen):
                    #if k not in (0, -1): continue #uncomment this if you want only first/last letters, suggested by Loewian
                    npermutations += 1
                    if [word[k] for word in words] == ["י", "ה", "ו", "ה"]:
                        forwards.append((perek, i, words, k))
                    if list(reversed([word[k] for word in words])) == ["י", "ה", "ו", "ה"]:
                        backwards.append((perek, i, words, k))
        perek = j["next"]
    return Result(forwards, backwards, npesukim, nwords, nletters, npermutations)

def produceresults(results={}): #run again after it's interrupted to continue where you left off
    for book in books:
        if book not in results:
            results[book] = gatherresults(book)
    return results

def realbook(book):
    for _ in "Kings", "Chronicles", "Samuel":
        if _ in book: return _
    if book == "Nehemiah": return "Ezra"
    return book

#run this line as many times as needed, it often fails for connection errors partway through
results = produceresults()

realresults = {realbook(book): Result() for book in results}

for book, result in results.items():
    realresults[realbook(book)] += result
```

Here's the code for printing all the results:

```
def ordinal(number):
    if number >= 0: number += 1
    if number == -1: return "last"
    result = str(abs(number))
    if abs(number) == 1: result += "st"
    elif abs(number) == 2: result += "nd"
    elif abs(number) == 3: result += "rd"
    else: result += "th"
    if number < 0: result += " last"
    return result

for book, result in realresults.items():
    if not (result.forwards or result.backwards): continue
    print(book)
    if result.forwards:
        print(" Forwards:")
        for perek, pasuk, words, idx in result.forwards:
            print(f"  {perek} {pasuk}, {ordinal(idx)} letter:", *words)
    if result.backwards:
        print(" Backwards:")
        for perek, pasuk, words, idx in result.backwards:
            print(f"  {perek} {pasuk}, {ordinal(idx)} letter:", *words)
```

```
Genesis
 Forwards:
  Genesis 1 3, 2nd last letter: אלהים יהי אור ויהי
  Genesis 12 15, last letter: שרי פרעה ויהללו אתה
  Genesis 19 13, last letter: פני יהוה וישלחנו יהוה
  Genesis 19 25, 1st letter: ישבי הערים וצמח האדמה
  Genesis 26 13, 4th last letter: ויגדל האיש וילך הלוך
  Genesis 38 7, last letter: בעיני יהוה וימתהו יהוה
  Genesis 43 10, last letter: כי עתה שבנו זה
  Genesis 44 15, 2nd letter: ויאמר להם יוסף מה
 Backwards:
  Genesis 11 9, 1st letter: הארץ ומשם הפיצם יהוה
  Genesis 24 58, last letter: לרבקה ויאמרו אליה התלכי
  Genesis 49 11, last letter: עירה עירו ולשרקה בני
  Genesis 49 31, last letter: רבקה אשתו ושמה קברתי
Exodus
 Forwards:
  Exodus 3 13, last letter: לי מה שמו מה
  Exodus 4 14, 1st letter: ידבר הוא וגם הנה
  Exodus 16 22, last letter: נשיאי העדה ויגידו למשה
  Exodus 36 36, 2nd letter: ויצפם זהב וויהם זהב
 Backwards:
  Exodus 4 3, last letter: ארצה וישליכהו ארצה ויהי
  Exodus 4 16, 1st letter: העם והיה הוא יהיה
  Exodus 16 7, last letter: יהוה ונחנו מה כי
  Exodus 25 23, last letter: ואמה רחבו ואמה וחצי
  Exodus 25 23, 4th letter: ואמה רחבו ואמה וחצי
  Exodus 26 37, 2nd letter: זהב וויהם זהב ויצקת
  Exodus 36 36, 2nd letter: זהב וויהם זהב ויצק
  Exodus 37 10, last letter: ואמה רחבו ואמה וחצי
  Exodus 37 10, 4th letter: ואמה רחבו ואמה וחצי
Leviticus
 Backwards:
  Leviticus 8 15, 1st letter: המזבח ואת הדם יצק
  Leviticus 8 29, last letter: החזה ויניפהו תנופה לפני
  Leviticus 9 9, 1st letter: המזבח ואת הדם יצק
  Leviticus 21 22, 1st letter: הקדשים ומן הקדשים יאכל
Numbers
 Forwards:
  Numbers 1 23, 4th letter: פקדיהם למטה שמעון תשעה
  Numbers 5 12, last letter: כי תשטה אשתו ומעלה
  Numbers 11 25, 2nd last letter: הזקנים ויהי כנוח עליהם
  Numbers 13 32, 1st letter: יושביה הוא וכל העם
 Backwards:
  Numbers 1 51, 5th last letter: הלוים ובחנת המשכן יקימו
  Numbers 1 51, 1st letter: הלוים ובחנת המשכן יקימו
  Numbers 1 51, 1st letter: הלוים והזר הקרב יומת
  Numbers 3 10, 4th last letter: כהנתם והזר הקרב יומת
  Numbers 5 18, 1st letter: הוא וביד הכהן יהיו
  Numbers 13 18, 3rd last letter: הוא ואת העם הישב
  Numbers 13 30, last letter: נעלה וירשנו אתה כי
  Numbers 19 12, 1st letter: השלישי וביום השביעי יטהר
  Numbers 24 13, last letter: טובה או רעה מלבי
Deuteronomy
 Forwards:
  Deuteronomy 11 2, 1st letter: ידו החזקה וזרעו הנטויה
  Deuteronomy 24 5, last letter: נקי יהיה לביתו שנה
  Deuteronomy 30 12, last letter: מי יעלה לנו השמימה
  Deuteronomy 31 29, last letter: בעיני יהוה להכעיסו במעשה
 Backwards:
  Deuteronomy 10 7, 1st letter: הגדגדה ומן הגדגדה יטבתה
  Deuteronomy 20 8, 1st letter: הירא ורך הלבב ילך
Joshua
 Forwards:
  Joshua 10 18, last letter: פי המערה והפקידו עליה
 Backwards:
  Joshua 2 15, 1st letter: החומה ובחומה היא יושבת
  Joshua 11 3, 5th last letter: והאמרי והחתי והפרזי והיבוסי
  Joshua 11 16, 1st letter: הערבה ואת הר ישראל
  Joshua 18 28, 1st letter: האלף והיבוסי היא ירושלם
  Joshua 19 47, last letter: אותה ויכו אותה לפי
  Joshua 24 18, 1st letter: העמים ואת האמרי ישב
  Joshua 24 27, last letter: תהיה בנו לעדה כי
Judges
 Forwards:
  Judges 16 16, last letter: כי הציקה לו בדבריה
  Judges 19 24, last letter: בתי הבתולה ופילגשהו אוציאה
  Judges 20 18, last letter: מי יעלה לנו בתחלה
  Judges 20 41, last letter: כי נגעה עליו הרעה
 Backwards:
  Judges 14 2, last letter: ועתה קחו אותה לי
Samuel
 Forwards:
  I Samuel 4 14, 2nd letter: ויאמר מה קול ההמון
  II Samuel 18 3, last letter: כי עתה כמנו עשרה
  II Samuel 18 4, 1st letter: יד השער וכל העם
  II Samuel 22 29, 4th letter: נירי יהוה ויהוה יגיה
 Backwards:
  I Samuel 20 21, last letter: והנה קחנו ובאה כי
  I Samuel 28 14, 3rd letter: עלה והוא עטה מעיל
  II Samuel 15 14, last letter: תהיה לנו פליטה מפני
  II Samuel 17 16, 4th letter: ועתה שלחו מהרה והגידו
  II Samuel 18 4, 1st letter: השער וכל העם יצאו
  II Samuel 22 29, 4th letter: יהוה ויהוה יגיה חשכי
Kings
 Forwards:
  I Kings 7 12, 1st letter: יהוה הפנימית ולאלם הבית
  I Kings 8 42, 1st letter: ידך החזקה וזרעך הנטויה
  I Kings 13 26, last letter: פי יהוה ויתנהו יהוה
  I Kings 16 7, last letter: בעיני יהוה להכעיסו במעשה
  I Kings 18 37, 1st letter: יהוה האלהים ואתה הסבת
  II Kings 4 18, 4th last letter: ויגדל הילד ויהי היום
  II Kings 10 1, 1st letter: יזרעאל הזקנים ואל האמנים
  II Kings 24 15, 4th letter: הוליך גולה מירושלם בבלה
  II Kings 24 20, 4th last letter: יהוה היתה בירושלם וביהודה
 Backwards:
  I Kings 18 3, 1st letter: הבית ועבדיהו היה ירא
  II Kings 2 14, 3rd letter: איה יהוה אלהי אליהו
  II Kings 7 2, 1st letter: האלהים ויאמר הנה יהוה
  II Kings 25 7, 2nd last letter: צדקיהו עור ויאסרהו בנחשתים
Isaiah
 Forwards:
  Isaiah 12 1, 3rd last letter: ביום ההוא אודך יהוה
  Isaiah 12 1, 2nd letter: ביום ההוא אודך יהוה
  Isaiah 12 4, 3rd last letter: ביום ההוא הודו ליהוה
  Isaiah 16 3, last letter: הביאי עצה עשו פלילה
  Isaiah 33 22, last letter: כי יהוה שפטנו יהוה
  Isaiah 42 12, 3rd letter: ישימו ליהוה כבוד ותהלתו
  Isaiah 45 18, 1st letter: יצר הארץ ועשה הוא
 Backwards:
  Isaiah 12 1, 2nd letter: ההוא אודך יהוה כי
  Isaiah 16 3, last letter: עצה עשו פלילה שיתי
  Isaiah 28 29, 4th letter: יהוה צבאות יצאה הפליא
  Isaiah 30 26, 4th last letter: החמה ואור החמה יהיה
  Isaiah 30 26, 1st letter: החמה ואור החמה יהיה
  Isaiah 35 2, 1st letter: הכרמל והשרון המה יראו
  Isaiah 42 12, 3rd letter: ליהוה כבוד ותהלתו באיים
  Isaiah 45 20, 1st letter: הקבצו ובאו התנגשו יחדו
Jeremiah
 Forwards:
  Jeremiah 9 11, last letter: פי יהוה אליו ויגדה
  Jeremiah 9 17, last letter: נהי ותרדנה עינינו דמעה
  Jeremiah 15 19, last letter: כפי תהיה ישבו המה
  Jeremiah 33 16, 2nd letter: בימים ההם תושע יהודה
  Jeremiah 49 19, last letter: כי ארגיעה אריצנו מעליה
  Jeremiah 50 4, 4th last letter: בימים ההמה ובעת ההיא
  Jeremiah 51 31, last letter: כי נלכדה עירו מקצה
  Jeremiah 52 3, 4th last letter: יהוה היתה בירושלם ויהודה
 Backwards:
  Jeremiah 22 8, 3rd letter: עשה יהוה ככה לעיר
  Jeremiah 31 7, 1st letter: הללו ואמרו הושע יהוה
  Jeremiah 33 16, 2nd letter: ההם תושע יהודה וירושלם
  Jeremiah 33 20, 1st letter: הלילה ולבלתי היות יומם
  Jeremiah 39 7, 2nd last letter: צדקיהו עור ויאסרהו בנחשתים
  Jeremiah 48 2, last letter: רעה לכו ונכריתנה מגוי
  Jeremiah 49 19, last letter: ארגיעה אריצנו מעליה ומי
  Jeremiah 50 15, last letter: אשיותיה נהרסו חומותיה כי
  Jeremiah 50 29, last letter: עשתה עשו לה כי
  Jeremiah 52 11, 2nd last letter: צדקיהו עור ויאסרהו בנחשתים
Ezekiel
 Forwards:
  Ezekiel 23 8, last letter: כי אותה שכבו בנעוריה
  Ezekiel 30 2, last letter: אדני יהוה הילילו הה
  Ezekiel 31 4, 2nd last letter: מים גדלוהו תהום רממתהו
  Ezekiel 31 15, last letter: עצי השדה עליו עלפה
  Ezekiel 46 1, 1st letter: ימי המעשה וביום השבת
 Backwards:
  Ezekiel 1 27, last letter: וממראה מתניו ולמטה ראיתי
  Ezekiel 46 1, 1st letter: המעשה וביום השבת יפתח
Hosea
 Forwards:
  Hosea 11 10, last letter: אחרי יהוה ילכו כאריה
Joel
 Forwards:
  Joel 2 7, last letter: כאנשי מלחמה יעלו חומה
  Joel 2 17, last letter: משרתי יהוה ויאמרו חוסה
  Joel 4 1, 4th last letter: בימים ההמה ובעת ההיא
Haggai
 Backwards:
  Haggai 2 3, 3rd letter: עתה הלוא כמהו כאין
Zechariah
 Forwards:
  Zechariah 9 17, last letter: כי מה טובו ומה
 Backwards:
  Zechariah 1 5, 1st letter: הם והנבאים הלעולם יחיו
  Zechariah 8 19, 1st letter: השביעי וצום העשירי יהיה
Psalms
 Forwards:
  Psalms 9 21, 2nd letter: שיתה יהוה מורה להם
  Psalms 40 6, 3rd letter: עשית אתה יהוה אלהי
  Psalms 57 7, last letter: לפני שיחה נפלו בתוכה
  Psalms 73 15, last letter: אמרתי אספרה כמו הנה
  Psalms 84 11, 3rd letter: בבית אלהי מדור באהלי
  Psalms 96 11, 1st letter: ישמחו השמים ותגל הארץ
  Psalms 107 24, last letter: מעשי יהוה ונפלאותיו במצולה
  Psalms 115 11, last letter: יראי יהוה בטחו ביהוה
  Psalms 118 28, 3rd letter: אלי אתה ואודך אלהי
 Backwards:
  Psalms 18 8, 1st letter: הארץ ומוסדי הרים ירגזו
  Psalms 69 24, 2nd last letter: עיניהם מראות ומתניהם תמיד
  Psalms 96 11, 1st letter: השמים ותגל הארץ ירעם
  Psalms 106 1, last letter: הללויה הודו ליהוה כי
  Psalms 146 10, 3rd last letter: יהוה לעולם אלהיך ציון
Proverbs
 Forwards:
  Proverbs 20 12, 3rd letter: ועין ראה יהוה עשה
Job
 Forwards:
  Job 18 11, 2nd last letter: סביב בעתהו בלהות והפיצהו
 Backwards:
  Job 18 11, 2nd last letter: בעתהו בלהות והפיצהו לרגליו
  Job 36 11, 2nd last letter: ימיהם בטוב ושניהם בנעימים
Ruth
 Backwards:
  Ruth 1 21, 1st letter: הלכתי וריקם השיבני יהוה
Lamentations
 Backwards:
  Lamentations 1 17, 2nd letter: לה צוה יהוה ליעקב
  Lamentations 3 33, last letter: ענה מלבו ויגה בני
Ecclesiastes
 Backwards:
  Ecclesiastes 3 17, 1st letter: הצדיק ואת הרשע ישפט
Esther
 Forwards:
  Esther 5 4, 4th last letter: יבוא המלך והמן היום
  Esther 5 4, 1st letter: יבוא המלך והמן היום
  Esther 7 7, last letter: כי כלתה אליו הרעה
 Backwards:
  Esther 1 20, 1st letter: היא וכל הנשים יתנו
  Esther 5 13, last letter: זה איננו שוה לי
Daniel
 Backwards:
  Daniel 4 1, 3rd letter: אנה נבוכדנצר שלה הוית
  Daniel 12 1, 4th last letter: ההיא ובעת ההיא ימלט
  Daniel 12 1, 1st letter: ההיא ובעת ההיא ימלט
Ezra
 Backwards:
  Ezra 8 19, last letter: חשביה ואתו ישעיה מבני
Chronicles
 Forwards:
  I Chronicles 5 12, 1st letter: יואל הראש ושפם המשנה
  I Chronicles 8 39, 1st letter: יעוש השני ואליפלט השלשי
  I Chronicles 16 31, 1st letter: ישמחו השמים ותגל הארץ
  I Chronicles 18 8, 1st letter: ים הנחשת ואת העמודים
  I Chronicles 22 18, 1st letter: ישבי הארץ ונכבשה הארץ
  I Chronicles 23 11, 1st letter: יחת הראש וזיזה השני
  I Chronicles 23 17, last letter: ובני רחביה רבו למעלה
  I Chronicles 23 19, 6th last letter: יחזיאל השלישי ויקמעם הרביעי
  I Chronicles 23 19, 1st letter: יחזיאל השלישי ויקמעם הרביעי
  I Chronicles 26 4, 1st letter: יואח השלשי ושכר הרביעי
  II Chronicles 20 34, 1st letter: יהושפט הראשנים והאחרנים הנם
  II Chronicles 24 6, 4th last letter: ויקרא המלך ליהוידע הראש
  II Chronicles 25 14, 2nd last letter: לאלהים ולפניהם ישתחוה ולהם
  II Chronicles 26 11, 1st letter: יעיאל הסופר ומעשיהו השוטר
  II Chronicles 27 3, 1st letter: יהוה העליון ובחומת העפל
 Backwards:
  I Chronicles 21 17, last letter: מה עשו יהוה אלהי
  I Chronicles 27 30, 1st letter: הישמעלי ועל האתנות יחדיהו
  II Chronicles 23 6, 1st letter: המה וכל העם ישמרו
  II Chronicles 24 6, 4th last letter: המלך ליהוידע הראש ויאמר
  II Chronicles 24 9, 4th last letter: ביהודה ובירושלם להביא ליהוה
  II Chronicles 26 17, 4th last letter: הכהן ועמו כהנים ליהוה
  II Chronicles 32 25, 3rd letter: גבה לבו ויהי עליו
```

Note that יבוא המלך והמן היום is counted twice, as the first and fourth-to-last letters, because the words are all the same length.  The same thing happens in DHY 1:23:19.  I didn't want to change the experiment after seeing the results, and statistically this could have happened anywhere, so I'm leaving those in.

Is the Megillah unusual?  Let's see the density of results in each book: how many times we find Hashem's name divided by the number of possible four letter combinations.

```
for book, result in sorted(realresults.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1].density):
    print(f"{book} {result.density:.2e}")

print("-------")
for unit, (start, end) in ("Torah", ("Genesis", "Deuteronomy")), ("Navi", ("Joshua", "Malachi")), ("  Trei Asar", ("Hosea", "Malachi")), ("Ketuvim", ("Psalms", "II Chronicles")), ("Tanach", ("Genesis", "II Chronicles")):
    start = books.index(start)
    end = books.index(end)
    includebooks = {realbook(book) for book in books[start:end+1]}
    total = sum(realresults[book] for book in includebooks)

    print(f"{unit} {total.density:.2e}")
```

```
Amos 0.00e+00
Obadiah 0.00e+00
Jonah 0.00e+00
Micah 0.00e+00
Nahum 0.00e+00
Habakkuk 0.00e+00
Zephaniah 0.00e+00
Malachi 0.00e+00
Song of Songs 0.00e+00
Ezra 1.25e-05
Proverbs 2.19e-05
Leviticus 4.19e-05
Ecclesiastes 4.25e-05
Ezekiel 4.29e-05
Samuel 4.89e-05
Deuteronomy 5.01e-05
Hosea 5.22e-05
Job 5.47e-05
Daniel 5.52e-05
Judges 5.95e-05
Kings 6.00e-05
Genesis 7.30e-05
Joshua 9.22e-05
Ruth 9.45e-05
Jeremiah 9.62e-05
Exodus 9.63e-05
Numbers 9.72e-05
Isaiah 1.04e-04
Chronicles 1.06e-04
Psalms 1.06e-04
Zechariah 1.12e-04
Lamentations 1.73e-04
Esther 1.84e-04
Haggai 1.90e-04
Joel 3.68e-04
-------
Torah 7.40e-05
Navi 6.96e-05
  Trei Asar 6.58e-05
Ketuvim 8.05e-05
Tanach 7.36e-05
```

***Conclusion: [If we count Trei Asar as 12 separate books](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15457/11532), Yoel has by far the highest density of hidden שמות הוי"ה using this search strategy, followed by Chaggai, the Megillah, and Eichah, which are all almost tied.***

---

Other possible strategies (to be taken with a grain of salt, because every time you try another new thing you also mess with the statistics):

[Counting Trei Asar as one book](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/97129/11532), the Megillah is the winner among the 24 books.  Eichah (another book of hester panim) is the close second.  This is probably what I should have done in the first place.

Loewian points out that it might be more reasonable to count only first letters or only last letters.  I'm ambivalent on that point, and now that we've seen the results there's room for bias here, but anyway, you can get those results by uncommenting one line in the code above (search for Loewian).  The Megillah is still the winner among 24, behind Yoel and Chaggai if you separate Trei Asar.

```
Amos 0.00e+00
Obadiah 0.00e+00
Jonah 0.00e+00
Micah 0.00e+00
Nahum 0.00e+00
Habakkuk 0.00e+00
Zephaniah 0.00e+00
Malachi 0.00e+00
Song of Songs 0.00e+00
Ezra 1.25e-05
Proverbs 2.19e-05
Leviticus 4.19e-05
Ecclesiastes 4.25e-05
Ezekiel 4.29e-05
Samuel 4.89e-05
Deuteronomy 5.01e-05
Hosea 5.22e-05
Job 5.47e-05
Daniel 5.52e-05
Judges 5.95e-05
Kings 6.00e-05
Genesis 7.30e-05
Joshua 9.22e-05
Ruth 9.45e-05
Jeremiah 9.62e-05
Exodus 9.63e-05
Numbers 9.72e-05
Isaiah 1.04e-04
Chronicles 1.06e-04
Psalms 1.06e-04
Zechariah 1.12e-04
Lamentations 1.73e-04
Esther 1.84e-04
Haggai 1.90e-04
Joel 3.68e-04
-------
Torah 7.40e-05
Navi 6.96e-05
  Trei Asar 6.58e-05
Ketuvim 8.05e-05
Tanach 7.36e-05
```

Comment: Disclaimer, which I was also going to write regardless of the results: whether or not any particular detail of the Megillah is statistically significant (turns out this one seems to be), the actual events described are ridiculously unlikely to happen by chance and are obviously a result of Hashem's hashgacha. I don't know that I would have noticed the theme of hester panim on my own, but once Chazal pointed it out it's impossible to miss.  [Maurice's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/111900/11532) is also obviously true regardless of anything else.

Comment: +1 Great answer. But shouldn't you have to control for the higher overall frequency in scripture of the letters of the Tetragrammaton, than, e.g., ג  or ט?  Also, I would think encoding as the first letter of a word is a more obvious code than 2nd letter backwards - which should suggest their significance is somewhat independent (i.e. meriting separate analyses).

Comment: @Loewian For your second point - I'm not sure I agree, but I added those results too.  On the first point - that's not really relevant because I'm not doing anything with the absolute densities, I'm just comparing between books.  I guess if there's a difference in letter frequency between books that would affect things but I don't want to introduce even more complexity (at a guess it would probably just be Eme"s vs. the rest).

Answer (score 4):

[Chapter](https://www.sie.org/templates/sie/article_cdo/aid/2865766/jewish/Chapter-Five.htm) 5, verse 4.

In the initials of the 4 words
יבא המלך והמן היום

Comment: Also backwards כי רבה היא וכל הנשים יתנו יקר

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about God's name being "concealed", but Mordechai tells Esther confidently that if she does not do her part, "release and liberation will materialize for the Jews from some other source".  What could that other source be except one engineered by Hashem?

> כִּ֣י אִם־הַחֲרֵ֣שׁ תַּחֲרִישִׁי֮ בָּעֵ֣ת הַזֹּאת֒ רֶ֣וַח וְהַצָּלָ֞ה יַעֲמ֤וֹד לַיְּהוּדִים֙ מִמָּק֣וֹם אַחֵ֔ר וְאַ֥תְּ וּבֵית־אָבִ֖יךְ תֹּאבֵ֑דוּ וּמִ֣י יוֹדֵ֔עַ אִם־לְעֵ֣ת כָּזֹ֔את הִגַּ֖עַתְּ לַמַּלְכֽוּת׃
>
> For, if you keep silent at this time, release and liberation will materialize for the Jews from some other source, and you and your father’s lineage will perish. Who knows whether, at this time next year, you will retain your royal position. [Esther 4:14]

Answer (score 1):

In his Sefer Ner lemeah al inyene Purim, R. Yeraḥmiel ben Zvi says that there is an allusion in Esther 7:7 by the final letter of four consecutive words read forward:

> כי כלתה אליו הרעה
>
> ki chaltah ailav hara’ah
>
> “that his fate had been determined.”

Comment: Also backwards וכל זה איננו שוה לי

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Yaakov Emden in his siddur (*Siddur Ya'avetz*, also known as *Beis Yaakov*), has a list of *sheimos,* names of Hashem that are found in the *Megilla*.  These include the Tetragrammaton (שם הוי"ה) in order (as in **י**בוא **ה**מלך **ו**המן **ה**יום) and out of order (such as לבד**ו** עות**ה** ושת**י** המלכ**ה** and ז**ה** איננ**ו** שו**ה** ל**י**)  as well as *sheimos*, often one of the 72 3-letter *sheimos* of ויסע ויבא ויט.

The list is too long to cite here, but I recall there being upwards of 30 references.